# MySQL: Select all rows with not matching timestamps in two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, comparison

I'm trying to compare two tables in different databases (or looking for a best way to do this).

Table in database one:

```
id  int(11) 
lastmod int(11)
```

Table in database two:

```
id          int(11) 
timestamp   int(11)
```

Both tables have matching ids (id is not unique in db1. Like one(db2) to many (db1)) and time stamps (but other columns differ). But with time, records in database two will be updated (data in one unimportant column). And now I need to find records (timestamps), comparing ids, to find which records I need to update in database one. 
Problem is also with performance, because both tables have more than 5 000 000 records. 
What is best way (most optimal) to find records which need to be updated?

Comment: You can update them in real time with some triggers. Otherwise you can join one table to the other and check if the timestamps are different.

Comment: For some reasons I can't use triggers. Can You please show me example join query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is a primary key in both tables, then the following should be efficient:

```
select *
from db1.table t1 join
     db2.table t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t1.lastmod <> t2.timestamp
```

Note that this assumes two things.  First, the `id` is unique in each table and second that the timestamp column is not `NULL`.

EDIT:

If the situation is that you have multiple modifications in `t1` and are trying to compare the results to `t2`, which has only one row, then aggregate `t1` first to get the most recent modification date and proceed from there:

```
select *
from (select t1.id, max(t1.lastmod) as lastmod
      from db1.table t1
      group by t1.id
     ) t1 join
     db2.table t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t1.lastmod <> t2.timestamp
```

If you are really looking for a record with more than one modification in `t1`, then add a `having count(*) > 1` to the subquery.

Comment: And what if id is not unique in db1? Like one(db2) to many (db1)